# Numbers factorization

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes, factorization

The task is to write function that foldes number into prime factors. By given number 'n' this function should return a list of tuples **p_i,c^i**, for example if input is 100, the output is (2,2),(5,2).
So, here is how i try to write it:

```
def factor(n):
c = 1
pre_ans = list()
temp_n=n
for i in range(2,temp_n+1):
    if (is_prime(i) == True) and (temp_n % i == 0):
        for j in range (2,temp_n+1):
            if (temp_n % (i ** j) == 0):
                pre_ans.append((i,j))
                temp_n /= (i **j)
        pre_ans.append((i,c))
        temp_n /= i
print(pre_ans)
```

It works wrong but I can't find a mistake :(

Comment: is_prime is function:
def is_prime(n):
    return n > 1 and all(n % i != 0 for i in range(2, n))

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Also, why haven't you included `is_prime` as a properly edited function in your question? Please edit it in.

Comment: my question is that why this exact code does not work right, though i find it ideologically correct. If i'm doing smth wrong, then please correct me

Comment: Please provide an example of your code's output for a given input.

Comment: factor(100) gives [(2,2),(2,1)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the code. This is working version

```
def factor(n):
c = 1
pre_ans = list()
temp_n=n
for i in range(2, n // 2 + 1):
    if (is_prime(i) == True):
        k = 1
        while temp_n % (i ** k) == 0:
            if temp_n % (i ** (k + 1)) == 0:
                k += 1
            else:
                k += 1
                break
        if k > 1:
            pre_ans.append((i, k - 1))
return pre_ans
```

Answer (score 0):

Your general idea is ok. However there are some minor issues with the following part of your code:

```
for j in range (2,temp_n+1):
    if (temp_n % (i ** j) == 0):
        pre_ans.append((i,j))
        temp_n /= (i **j)
pre_ans.append((i,c))
temp_n /= i
```

In fact the main problem is that you need to iterate in the other direction in this statement `for j in range (2,temp_n+1)`. If you rewrite it like

```
def factor(n):
    c = 1
    pre_ans = list()
    temp_n=n
    for i in range(2,temp_n+1):
        if (is_prime(i) == True) and (temp_n % i == 0):
            for j in range (temp_n+1, 0,-1):
                if (temp_n % (i ** j) == 0):
                    pre_ans.append((i,j))
                    temp_n /= (i **j)
    print(pre_ans)
```

it will work. The whole code can also get written a bit shorter:

```
from collections import Counter

def factor(n):
    lst = []
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        while n % i == 0:
            lst.append(i)
            n = n / i
    return Counter(lst).items()

print(factor(100))
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question _at all_?

Comment: It's not a short solution. Where are you processing a list of tuples and where are you giving out prime factors? It's almost like you've just dumped code from another question.

Comment: @roganjosh A list of tupels is returned by the Counter function. Don't need to do this by myself.